Decrypting a p7m file using CNG
I have existing legacy Crypto API code that worked OK-ish until recently - I am seeing more and more cases when the data is not being decrypted at all without returning any errors (CryptMsgOpenToDecode / CryptMsgUpdate) or outright fails if the key is stored in a CNG KSP provider.
So I am trying to switch to the shiny new CNG API, but having trouble making it work - hours of conversing with ChatGPT and browsing through the existing GitHub code did not get me any closer. I can post my existing code (one of a couple dozen versions I tried to satisfy the "what have you tried?" requirement), but that won't be very helpful.
What I am looking for is the outline of the steps I need to take to use CNG API to decrypt a p7m blob. Am I correct in  assuming that I need to do the following?

NCryptOpenStorageProvider
Figure out the key used to encrypt the blob
Open the key using NCryptOpenKey
Decrypt the blob using NCryptDecrypt.

I am having problems with step (2) - probably wouldn't be a good idea to loop through all installed keys and try to use them one at a time to decrypt the data, right? My latest attempt is using CryptMsgOpenToDecode / CryptMsgUpdate / CryptMsgGetParam(CMSG_RECIPIENT_COUNT_PARAM / CMSG_RECIPIENT_INFO_PARAM). But these functions are not CNG, they are legacy. How do I do that in CNG? Or am I totally off and I need to do things differently?

CryptMsgOpenToDecode / CryptMsgUpdate - this is not legacy api or CNG api. it work with both. really show your code


But these functions are not CNG, they are legacy. How do I do that in
CNG

all CryptMsg* functions not legacy or CNG. this at all another api set and internal can use both (legacy or CNG) for encrypt and decrypt, sign and verify.
usual sequence of calls is next:

CryptMsgOpenToDecode
CryptMsgUpdate
CryptMsgGetParam(CMSG_RECIPIENT_COUNT_PARAM)
CryptMsgGetParam(CMSG_RECIPIENT_INFO_PARAM) in loop
CertGetSubjectCertificateFromStore
CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey
CryptMsgControl(CMSG_CTRL_DECRYPT)
CryptMsgGetParam(CMSG_CONTENT_PARAM)

code example:
template <typename T> 
T HR(HRESULT& hr, T t)
{
    hr = t ? NOERROR : GetLastError();
    return t;
}

HRESULT GetMsgType(_In_ HCRYPTMSG hCryptMsg, _Out_ PULONG dwMsgType)
{
    ULONG cb = sizeof(ULONG);
    HRESULT hr;
    HR(hr, CryptMsgGetParam(hCryptMsg, CMSG_TYPE_PARAM, 0, dwMsgType, &cb));
    return hr;
}

HRESULT IsEncryptedMessage(_In_ HCRYPTMSG hCryptMsg)
{
    ULONG dwMsgType;

    HRESULT hr = GetMsgType(hCryptMsg, &dwMsgType);

    if (0 <= hr)
    {
        return dwMsgType == CMSG_ENVELOPED ? S_OK : HRESULT_FROM_NT(STATUS_OBJECT_TYPE_MISMATCH);
    }

    return hr;
}

HRESULT GetKey(_In_ HCERTSTORE hCertStore, 
               _In_ HCRYPTMSG hCryptMsg, 
               _Inout_ PCMSG_CTRL_DECRYPT_PARA pcdp,
               _Out_ BOOL *pfCallerFreeProvOrNCryptKey)
{
    ULONG cb = 0;
    PCERT_INFO pCertId = 0;

    HRESULT hr;
    while (HR(hr, CryptMsgGetParam(hCryptMsg, CMSG_RECIPIENT_INFO_PARAM, pcdp->dwRecipientIndex, pCertId, &cb)))
    {
        if (pCertId)
        {
            if (PCCERT_CONTEXT pCertContext = HR(hr, CertGetSubjectCertificateFromStore(hCertStore, X509_ASN_ENCODING, pCertId)))
            {
                HR(hr, CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey(pCertContext, 
                    CRYPT_ACQUIRE_COMPARE_KEY_FLAG|CRYPT_ACQUIRE_PREFER_NCRYPT_KEY_FLAG,
                    0, &pcdp->hNCryptKey, &pcdp->dwKeySpec, pfCallerFreeProvOrNCryptKey));

                CertFreeCertificateContext(pCertContext);
            }

            break;
        }

        pCertId = (PCERT_INFO)alloca(cb);
    }

    return hr;
}

HRESULT Decrypt(_In_ HCERTSTORE hCertStore, _In_ const BYTE* pbEncodedBlob, _In_ ULONG cbEncodedBlob, _Out_ PDATA_BLOB pContent)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    if (HCRYPTMSG hCryptMsg = HR(hr, CryptMsgOpenToDecode(PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)))
    {
        if (HR(hr, CryptMsgUpdate(hCryptMsg, pbEncodedBlob, cbEncodedBlob, TRUE)))
        {
            if (S_OK == (hr = IsEncryptedMessage(hCryptMsg)))
            {
                CMSG_CTRL_DECRYPT_PARA cdp = { sizeof(cdp) };

                ULONG cb;

                if (HR(hr, CryptMsgGetParam(hCryptMsg, CMSG_RECIPIENT_COUNT_PARAM, 0, &cdp.dwRecipientIndex, &(cb = sizeof(ULONG)))))
                {
                    hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NOT_FOUND);

                    if (cdp.dwRecipientIndex)
                    {
                        do 
                        {
                            --cdp.dwRecipientIndex;

                            BOOL fCallerFreeProvOrNCryptKey;
                            
                            if (S_OK == (hr = GetKey(hCertStore, hCryptMsg, &cdp, &fCallerFreeProvOrNCryptKey)))
                            {
                                if (HR(hr, CryptMsgControl(hCryptMsg, 0, CMSG_CTRL_DECRYPT, &cdp)))
                                {
                                    cdp.dwRecipientIndex = 0;

                                    PBYTE pb = 0;
                                    cb = 0;

                                    while (HR(hr, CryptMsgGetParam(hCryptMsg, CMSG_CONTENT_PARAM, 0, pb, &cb)))
                                    {
                                        if (pb)
                                        {
                                            if (pContent)
                                            {
                                                pContent->pbData = pb;
                                                pContent->cbData = cb;
                                                pb = 0;
                                            }
                                            break;
                                        }

                                        if (!(pb = new BYTE[cb]))
                                        {
                                            hr = E_OUTOFMEMORY;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    if (pb)
                                    {
                                        delete [] pb;
                                    }

                                    break;
                                }

                                if (fCallerFreeProvOrNCryptKey)
                                {
                                    if (CERT_NCRYPT_KEY_SPEC == cdp.dwKeySpec)
                                    {
                                        NCryptFreeObject(cdp.hNCryptKey);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        CryptReleaseContext(cdp.hCryptProv, 0);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        } while (cdp.dwRecipientIndex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        CryptMsgClose(hCryptMsg);
    }

    return hr;
}

HRESULT Decrypt(_In_ const BYTE* pbEncodedBlob, _In_ ULONG cbEncodedBlob, _Out_ PDATA_BLOB pContent)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    if (HCERTSTORE hCertStore = HR(hr, CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM, 0, 0, 
        CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER|CERT_STORE_OPEN_EXISTING_FLAG|CERT_STORE_READONLY_FLAG, L"My")))
    {
        hr = Decrypt(hCertStore, pbEncodedBlob, cbEncodedBlob, pContent);
        CertCloseStore(hCertStore, 0);
    }

    return hr;
}

void TestMsgDecrypt(_In_ const BYTE* pbEncodedBlob, _In_ ULONG cbEncodedBlob)
{
    DATA_BLOB db;
    if (S_OK == Decrypt(pbEncodedBlob, cbEncodedBlob, &db))
    {
        delete [] db.pbData;
    }
}

for create encrypted message for test possible use this code:
HRESULT EncryptMsg(_In_ PCCERT_CONTEXT pCertContext, _In_ PBYTE pbMsg, _In_ ULONG cbMsg, _Out_ PBYTE* ppb, _Out_ ULONG* pcb)
{
    HRESULT hr;

    CMSG_ENVELOPED_ENCODE_INFO EnvelopedEncodeInfo = { 
        sizeof(EnvelopedEncodeInfo), 0, { const_cast<PSTR>(szOID_NIST_AES256_CBC) }, 
        0, 1, const_cast<PCERT_INFO*>(&pCertContext->pCertInfo)
    }; 

    if (HCRYPTMSG hCryptMsg = HR(hr, CryptMsgOpenToEncode(
        PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, 0, CMSG_ENVELOPED, &EnvelopedEncodeInfo, 0, 0)))
    {
        if (HR(hr, CryptMsgUpdate(hCryptMsg, pbMsg, cbMsg, TRUE)))
        {
            PBYTE pbEncodedBlob = 0;
            ULONG cbEncodedBlob = 0;

            while (HR(hr, CryptMsgGetParam(hCryptMsg, CMSG_CONTENT_PARAM, 0, pbEncodedBlob, &cbEncodedBlob)))
            {
                if (pbEncodedBlob)
                {
                    *ppb = pbEncodedBlob, *pcb = cbEncodedBlob, pbEncodedBlob = 0;
                    break;
                }

                if (!(pbEncodedBlob = new UCHAR[cbEncodedBlob]))
                {
                    hr = E_OUTOFMEMORY;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (pbEncodedBlob)
            {
                delete [] pbEncodedBlob;
            }
        }

        CryptMsgClose(hCryptMsg);
    }

    return hr;
}

complete test (encode + decode)
HRESULT GetCert(_Out_ PCCERT_CONTEXT* ppCertContext, 
              _In_ PCSTR pszCertHash, 
              _In_ ULONG dwFlags = CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER|CERT_STORE_OPEN_EXISTING_FLAG|CERT_STORE_READONLY_FLAG)
{
    HRESULT hr;

    UCHAR hash[20];
    DATA_BLOB db = { sizeof(hash), hash };

    if (HR(hr, CryptStringToBinaryA(pszCertHash, 0, CRYPT_STRING_HEX, hash, &db.cbData, 0, 0)))
    {
        if (HCERTSTORE hCertStore = HR(hr, CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM, 0, 0, dwFlags, L"My")))
        {
            *ppCertContext = HR(hr, CertFindCertificateInStore(hCertStore, 0, 0, CERT_FIND_HASH, &db, 0));
            CertCloseStore(hCertStore, 0);
        }
    }

    return hr;
}

HRESULT EncH(_In_ PCSTR pszCertHash, _In_ PBYTE pbMsg, _In_ ULONG cbMsg, _Out_ PBYTE* ppb, _Out_ ULONG* pcb)
{
    PCCERT_CONTEXT pCertContext;
    ULONG hr;
    if (NOERROR == (hr = GetCert(&pCertContext, pszCertHash)))
    {
        hr = EncryptMsg(pCertContext, pbMsg, cbMsg, ppb, pcb);
        CertFreeCertificateContext(pCertContext);
    }

    return hr;
}

void HTest(PCSTR pcsz)
{
    PBYTE pb;
    ULONG cb;
    if (NOERROR == EncH("***", (PBYTE)pcsz, (ULONG)strlen(pcsz), &pb, &cb))
    {
        TestMsgDecrypt(pb, cb);
        delete [] pb;
    }
}

